# CSS only: horizontal buttons

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to create 2 horizontal buttons with the same width - based on the width of the longest one.

- The text content of each button can be adjusted by users on a separate page... thus I have no control over the length of their text / the length of the 1st vs 2nd button text.
- I would like to buttons to **adjust to the length of the longest text**, but **not exceed the width of the page** (on mobile for ex.).
- I would like the buttons to be **displayed horizontally by default**, but **stacked as columns if they don't fit horizontally**.
- I need to text of buttons to **break into multiple lines** if the whole text does not fit.

```
<div class="button-container">
     <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="yes">Yes</div>
     <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="no">No, sorry - I cannot make it</div>
</div>
```

I have tried multiple options... without being able to make it work!

- When using grid width grid-template-colums: 1fr 1fr, I can't find a way to 'stack' the buttons as columns when required.
- When using flex with flex:1 1 0, I can't find a way to make the buttons width adapt to the length of the text.

Please help!

1,000 thanks!
Damien.

Comment: Have you tried using `Media Queries to change the layout depending on if it reaches a certain width? If you don't know about them please check this [post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Media queries will change the layout based on the size of the screen - not based on the size of the text inside the buttons... I can't think of any way Media queries can help here. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: If you're asking it to be only `CSS` I don't think it is possible. We would have to involve `JS` to actually get the length of the text and increase it as needed.

Comment: You say *The text content of each button can be adjusted by users on a separate page*. How is the text being echoed out into the page? You could add an inline style to each button based on the longest text e.g `min-width: {{ $longestTextlength }}ch`

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this option. What do you dislike about this approach?

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.button-container {
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
}

.horizontal-button {
  padding: 16px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: hypens;
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .button-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="yes">Yes</div>
  <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="no">No, sorry - I cannot make it</div>
</div>
```

**A:** In this case, the container / the buttons take the full width of the page... they don't adjust to the width of the text

**Q:** Okay then so:

```css
div {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.button-container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 16px;
  max-width: max-content;
}

.horizontal-button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 50%;
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  .button-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .horizontal-button {
    hyphens: auto;
    max-width: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="yes">Yes</div>
  <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="no">No, sorry - I cannot make it</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, the container / the buttons take the full width of the page... they don't adjust to the width of the text.

Comment: The size of the `button-container` can be adjusted to the width necessary with `Media Querries` if you're really fussy about the width just add a number of `queries` to get that affect. The more queries with a different widths in pixel can give a good affect of screen re-sizing

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist next iterations...

Comment: @AndreiFedorov The answer is looking great that comment was more towards the person who asked. It's not possible to do what he really wants with only CSS without involving JS and the other workaround is to add media queries for every 100px-250px max to create an illusion of dynamic screen-resizing. I've done it somewhere before I just cant find it atm.

Comment: @ThisQRequiresASpecialist Sorry, english is not my native, confused) I tried to get the author's attention.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to dive in to a bit of Javascript imho. You look at the resize event take the largest width and set the width of all buttons to that.  However with display:flex, if you crush the screen size too much, the smaller buttons will shrink.

```js
window.onresize = () => {
  resizeButtons();
}

window.onload = () => {
  resizeButtons();
}

function resizeButtons() {
  const element = document.querySelector('.button-container');
  const buttons = element.querySelectorAll('.horizontal-button');
  var maxWidth = 0;
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.style.width = "";
  });
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    maxWidth = Math.max(button.offsetWidth, maxWidth);
  });
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.style.width = (maxWidth) + "px";
  });
}
```

```css
.button-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.25rem;
}

.horizontal-button {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.horizontal-button:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="yes">Yes</div>
    <div class="horizontal-button" data-role="no">No, sorry - I cannot make it</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution. You say that the text content of the buttons is user generated. This means you could do some calculation to find the longest length string and use it as an inline style to make both the buttons the same width.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.button-container {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.horizontal-button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
  <button class="horizontal-button" data-role="yes" style="width: 28ch">Yes</button>
  <button class="horizontal-button" data-role="no" style="width: 28ch">No, sorry - I cannot make it</button>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
  <button class="horizontal-button" data-role="yes" style="width: 65ch">Yes</button>
  <button class="horizontal-button" data-role="no" style="width: 65ch">No, sorry - I cannot make it, here is more text to make it longer</button>
</div>
```

How you go about calculating the longest string is dependant on what framework you are using.

For example Vue:

```
:style="`width: ${yes.length > no.length ? yes.length : no.length}ch``"
```

And this could easily be converted to work with PHP, React, Laravel etc...